# Why does the code in c# differs from the code in c when I write the same algorithm?

Tags: c#, c

Function in C

```
unsigned long int ROTL(unsigned long int x, unsigned long int  y)
    {
        return ((x) << (y&(32 - 1))) | ((x) >> (32 - (y&(32 - 1))));
    }
```

Function in C#

```
 uint ROTL(uint x, uint y) 
   { 
       return ((x) << (int)(y & (32 - 1))) | ((x) >> (int)(32- (y & (32 - 1)))); 
   }
```

above functions do the same work and the same result for small numbers,
but when I pass large numbers the result in C# differ from C.

Is there any problem in casting or in the function itself? Also I try to convert using

```
Convert.ToInt32()
```

Comment: "but when I pass large numbers" - How large are the numbers we're talking about?

Comment: What is the difference? Which code according to you returns the correct result?

Comment: What do you mean saying "large numbers"?

Comment: @PeterWurzinger more than signed int limit

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the c code

Comment: use Convert.ToInt64()

Comment: Add to your question what content you pass in, what the results are that you get, and what you would actually expect to happen.

Comment: @PouriaAnsari more than signed int limit (i.e.3232323232)

Comment: @PouriaAnsari Can not apply >> operator using uint and long

Comment: @Bart its a long algorithm :(

Comment: You don't have to use these operators If you need to work with bigger numbers define your own type.

Comment: @PouriaAnsari bitwise shift operator do not accept else the int for the offset number

Comment: I said you need to change your code on yourself.There is no any "only solution" to your question.

Comment: How long is a `long int` in this flavour of C ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `unsigned long int` translates to a unsigned 64bit integer you want to maybe go with C#s `ulong` instead of `uint`.

The main problem there is not the cast to `int` of the y-parameter, since it only takes the last 5 bits anyway. But when x is of type `uint` a bitshift with (worst case) 31 places exceeds its limits by far.
Casting and returning it to `ulong` could do the trick.

```
ulong ROTL(uint x, uint y) 
{ 
    return (((ulong)x) << (int)(y & (32 - 1))) | (((ulong)x) >> (int)(32 - (y & (32 - 1)))); 
}
```

Please note, that I did not test this throughly, but only did some boundary tests: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0ETAEL

EDIT: When you expect the results to be bigger than 2^64 (or as Parameter values: `ROTL(uint.MaxValue, 31)`) you should consider having a look at [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger).